# Opening iOS Passbook app from iOS Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-safari, passbook

I have a website where I offer to Download a Pass to Passbook.

After clicking on it on an Iphone the pass opens up and lets me save it to Passbook. After I click on add I am again on the previous Safari website.

Is there any chance I can then open the Passbook App programatically from Safari? Some kind of URL scheme?

Similar to this one here?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH1-SW1

Comment: You can use the shoebox:// schema, although this will only open the Passbook App.  It is undocumented, but has been available since iOS6.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with the Shoebox schema. Can you make an example?

Comment: It's completely undocumented so nobody other than Apple engineers are familiar with it. '<a href="shoebox://">Open Passbook</a>' is all we know.